# PHP preg_match numbers length

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to validate phone numbers and am struggling with this code. When I input a mobile number(0-9) with a length of either 10 or 11 I get invalid mobile number. Any ideas?

```
if (!preg_match('[0-9]{10,11}', $mobileNumber)) {
    echo("invalid mobile number");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: **Protip:** You should enable error reporting when developing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're missing the regex delimiters:

```
if (!preg_match('/[0-9]{10,11}/', $mobileNumber)) {
    echo("invalid mobile number");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: And I believe you forgot the start and end anchors `^$`